# R and dplyr: how to use ifelse condition with an external dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, apache-spark, dplyr

I'm using dplyr and spark to create a new variable with the mutate command. This new variable `new_variable` is categorical and must be `ALFA` if the value of the variable `my_data_variable` is inside a column of another dataframe `other_df$one_column`. Consequently its value will be `BETA` if its value it 
it is not included in the values ​​of `other_df$one_column`

an example of what I did:

```
my_data %>%
     mutate(new_variable = ifelse(my_data_variable == other_df$one_column, "ALFA","BETA"))
```

but unfortunately I get this error. Even using `!!other_df$one_column` or `local(other_df[['one_column']])` 
instead of `other_df$one_column` does not work.

```
Error: Cannot embed a data frame in a SQL query.

If you are seeing this error in code that used to work, the most likely cause is a change dbplyr 1.4.0. Previously `df$x` or
`df[[y]]` implied that `df` was a local variable, but now you must make that explict with `!!` or `local()`, e.g., `!!df$x` or
`local(df[["y"]))
```

Are there alternative methods to the ifelse function to get the expected result?

Comment: Not sure if this will work with spark but if you have more than one value in `other_df$one_column` you should probably use `my_data %>%
     mutate(new_variable = ifelse(my_data_variable %in% other_df$one_column, "ALFA","BETA"))`

Comment: @RonakShah I have now found the solution, thanks to your help. the solution is: 
     my_data %>%
     mutate(new_variable = ifelse(my_data_variable %in% !!other_df$one_column, "ALFA","BETA"))

Comment: great ! you should probably add that as an answer then.

Comment: @PabloPicciau, just add your solution in the area below `Your answer` and then you can validate it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @RonakShah for his help. The solution is the following:

```
my_data %>% 
     mutate(new_variable = ifelse(my_data_variable %in% !!other_df$one_column, "ALFA","BETA"))
```